# App Name not updating in ipa to upload in MDM - iOS

Tags: ios, xcode, plist, mdm, bundle-identifier

I created ios Application "PetFinder" and wanted to create separate environments for my app and so created Schemes Debug, QA, Preprod & Prod

I have different bundle-identifier and provisioning profiles for each environment

When I update my Bundle display name according to scheme, it works perfectly when I run from Xcode (For Eg: For QA scheme, my app name in device shows "PetFinder-QA" as expected

My problem is: When QA scheme is selected, generated ipa and try to update in my MDM, App name still shows as PetFinder. (I verified that this has bundle-identifier pointing to QA "com.xyzcompany.petfinder-qa" which is correct)

Below is how my info.plist is being set up

[image]
[image]
[image]

I've tried setting Bundle display name dynamically using variables. As mentioned, this works when i run from Xcode to my device but not when I ship my ipa to MDM

Added display name from user-defined variables in Build settings

Please refer attached screens

Actual should be when QA scheme selected, it should display my app name as "PetFinder-QA"

Comment: I suspect it is because when you build for distributing your app through your MDM, then Xcode uses the Release configuration.

Comment: You are right..i had Release config selected for my Archive in Schemes..Changing that to QA scheme resolved my issue..Thanks